# jni работа с Русскими символами

Tags: java, jni

Добрый день, работаю с библиотекой jacob, которая написана с помощью jni. Там есть исходники с++. Как мне можно передать русскую строку?
Вот кусок кода:

```
const char *progid = env->GetStringUTFChars(_progid, 0);
CLSID clsid;
HRESULT hr;
IUnknown *punk = NULL;
IDispatch *pIDispatch;
USES_CONVERSION;
LPOLESTR bsProgId = A2W(progid);
if (strchr(progid,':')) 
{
 env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(_progid, progid);
 // it's a moniker
 hr = CoGetObject(bsProgId, NULL, IID_IUnknown, (LPVOID *)&punk);
```

Прочитал что функция GetStringUTFChars не работает с русскими символами, как мне быть?

Comment: Если я использую эту функцию, то он мне возвращает такую строку WinNT://IUMAG/РђРґРјРёРЅРёСЃС‚СЂР°С‚РѕСЂ,user

Comment: Уточните кто это "он" и где возвращает, а лучше приведите код с комментариями от получения строки, до места вывода. Из приведенного кода непонятно откуда он (ваш он, или из этой библиотеки), почему приведён именно он и в каком месте выводится неправильная строка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ура. Все получилось!
Пришлось перекомпилировать dll и в Dispatch.cpp поменять

```
LPWSTR bsProgId = A2W(progid);
```

на

```
wchar_t* bsProgId = new wchar_t[4096];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, progid, -1, bsProgId, 4096);
```